# how to use jq tools or python as a output encoder to make result to translate to json formot is a difficult question

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, shell, jq

**for a example**

[root@test ~]# mysql -uroot -p'123123' -e"select user,host from mysql.user;"

```
+-------------------+-----------+
| user              | host      |
+-------------------+-----------+
| root              | %         |
| test              | %         |
| sqlaudit_test_mon | %         |
| sysbase_test      | %         |
| mysql.session     | localhost |
| mysql.sys         | localhost |
+-------------------+-----------+
```

how to make search the result quick to convert to json format can you jq tools or python
such as that out put

```
[
        {
                 "user":"root","host":"%"},
        {
                 "user":"test","host":"%"},     
        {
                 "user":"sqlaudit_test_mon","host":"%"},
        {
                 "user":"sysbase_test","host":"%"},
        {
                 "user":"mysql.session","host":"localhost"},
        {
                 "user":"mysql.sys","host":"localhost"}                  
]
```

i just want to know how to quick make search result to json,thank you!
it is better to user jq or python script it can make me search result to json format.

Comment: You probably want to start with the `-r` option to simplify the output from `mysql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it in your SELECT instead of pulling another program into a pipeline. MySQL has [JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html). Ones of interest here are `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` and `JSON_OBJECT()`. Something like:

```
SELECT json_arrayagg(json_object('user', user, 'host', host)) FROM mysql.user;
```

should do it, plus whatever's needed to not print out that fancy table ascii art.

Comment: ERROR 1305 (42000) at line 1: FUNCTION mysql.json_arrayagg does not exist

Comment: @jiaqiangliu What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: i am just a example ,i just want to ask how to use jq tools or json to quick to make output translatetions to json,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an all-jq solution that assumes an invocation like this:

```
jq -Rcn -f program.jq sql.txt
```

Note in particular the -R ("raw input") and -n options.

```
def trim: sub(" *$";"") | sub("^ *";"");

# input: an array of values
def objectify($headers):
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; $headers|length) as $i ({}; .[$headers[$i]] = ($in[$i]) ) ;

def preprocess:
  select( startswith("|") )
  | split("|")
  | .[1:-1]
  | map(trim) ;

reduce (inputs|preprocess) as $in (null;
    if . == null then {header: $in}
    else .header as $h
    | .table += [$in|objectify($h)]
    end )
  | .table
```